# How to perform fortify scan on different pl/sql files

Tags: c#, oracle, file, command-line, fortify

I am trying to do fortify scan on sql and oracle files from c# code. i have some folder which contains different oracle script files with extensions such as .pls, .pkb & .ddl etc.

Following are the commands i am executing to scan all files.

Command1: `sourceanalyzer -b test –clean`
Command2: 
a) `sourceanalyzer -b test -Dcom.fortify.sca.fileextensions.class=PLSQL C:\RapidWorkspace\TFS2\MFG-FDL-16_45418-20171114181758\PROD\RELEASE\**\*.*`

b) `sourceanalyzer -b test -Dcom.fortify.sca.fileextensions.pls=PLSQL C:\RapidWorkspace\TFS2\MFG-FDL-16_45418-20171114181758\PROD\RELEASE\**\*.*`

Command3: `sourceanalyzer -b test -scan -verbose -f Results.fpr`

Command2 -> a)  here i am able to scan .pls files. Even though its present in the folder i am searching. 
Command2 -> b) This command will only scan .pls files but not .pkb or other oracle files.

Please help me to find a command which can scan all different oracle extension files at once.

Thanks in Advance,
Asma

Comment: Sorry the command to search different files is as follows        
sourceanalyzer -b test -Dcom.fortify.sca.fileextensions.pls=PLSQL C:\RapidWorkspace\TFS2\MFG-FDL-16_45418-20171114181758\PROD\RELEASE\**\*.*

Comment: You can edit your post to correct the information you originally posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to modify the `fortify-sca.properties` file to add in the new file extensions.

Default Location: `C:\Program Files\HPE_Security\Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_17.10\Core\config\fortify-sca.properties`

There are several places you need to modify:

1) Add in filename extentions to map to your PLSQL files, you can see existing ones around line 63:

```
com.fortify.sca.fileextensions.pks        = PLSQL
com.fortify.sca.fileextensions.pkh        = PLSQL
com.fortify.sca.fileextensions.pkb        = PLSQL
```

Add in your file extensions below this line, for example:

```
com.fortify.sca.fileextensions.pls        = PLSQL
com.fortify.sca.fileextensions.ddl        = PLSQL
```

2) Any file extensions you added, you need to add them to the `com.fortify.sca.DefaultFileTypes` list that is around line 26.  (This is the list that is used when doing the wild card search `**/*`)

3) If you are always going to be scanning PLSQL (and not TSQL) and you are on windows then you can change the default SQL type to `PLSQL`.

This is around line 127, name `com.fortify.sca.SqlLanguage` and change the TSQL to PLSQL.

If you will be switching between TSQL and PLSQL on SQL files that end in the `.sql` file extension then add one of these commands to your translate commands:

```
-Dcom.fortify.sca.fileextensions.sql=PLSQL
-Dcom.fortify.sca.fileextensions.sql=TSQL
```

Examples (taken from `sourceanalyzer -h`):

```
sourceanalyzer -b mybuild -Dcom.fortify.sca.fileextensions.sql=PLSQL *.sql
sourceanalyzer -b mybuild -Dcom.fortify.sca.fileextensions.sql=TSQL *.sql
```

Then you can run the following commands

```
sourceanalyzer -b test -clean

sourceanalyzer -b test C:\RapidWorkspace\TFS2\MFG-FDL-16_45418-20171114181758\PROD\RELEASE\**\*.*
```

Then run `sourceanalyzer -b test -show-files`  This will show you the files that sourceanalyzer translated.  Ideally, your PLSQL files will be in this list.

Another command to check is `sourceanalyzer -b test -show-build-warnings`  This will show any issues sourceanalyzer had in translating the files.